# Unable to Configure cordova package in Visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, cordova, 2d, visual-studio-cordova

I am just starting learning "Build 2D games with HTML5" from MVA and in starting i had a problem to configure my visual studio 
Here is the link of that package [Cordova-Windows package](http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-wp8-3.5.0.zip)
The instructor shows that the Cordova windows package 3.5.0 contains CreateTemplates.bat file but it didn't work for me

[image]

i came up with this problem i dont know how to overcome this,
when i clicked the createTemplates.bat file its popup and off nothing happends so i try to open it up using command prompt and i get this errors , How to overcome? 
what should i do now , your help would be highly appreciable !

Answer (score 0):

You should use be using the Cordova CLI for your command line workflow for building Cordova Apps. For Cordova, more information is available [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html). If you want to use VS, then I strongly urge you to install our VS 2015 RC build which enables you to build Cordova applications for iOS, Android and Windows. More information for VS, is available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs).